# How to hide one activity screen (Dialog theme activity) above main screen and run hide activity in background?

Tags: android, android-activity

My Project have two Screen in which Activity A and Activity B.

Activity A show full screen with some content and activity B show audio player.

i need to when user minimize the player then player screen Activity B hide and play audio in background. Show only A activity Screen...

Please check demo screen layout on these [link](http://screencast.com/t/BM7GrVAli5E2)

http://screencast.com/t/BM7GrVAli5E2

can anyone suggest me how its possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using Activity B, use [android.widget.PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your ActivityB should act like a remote command for a Service which will actually handle the music playing.

- Invoke ActivityB
- When user taps play, start the service
- Close ActivityB, the service still plays music in the background

See this tutorial about implementing a mediaplayer service:
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/musicdroid-audio-player-part-ii